# Finding real world coordinate(3D) from 2D coordinates

Tags: matlab, 3d, computer-vision, projection

I have x, y coordinates of a feature from a single photograph. I know camera parameters. How can i get the 3D coordinate of that feature  (in matlab). please help me.

Comment: Which "camera parameters" do you know?

Comment: The topic is called 2D/3D registration.

Answer (score 1):

Give a look to this: http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~langer/558/4-cameramodel.pdf

Comment: I have read the lecture notes and understood that if i know focal length and pixel coordinate of principle point of the camera and the elevation of the camera then I can calculate (X,Y,Z) in camera coordinate system. Then with the use of camera location (in real world coordinate) i can calculate the object coordinate in world coordinate system. Am I understood correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Systems like this that I've seen before requires that you know where the camera is (latitude and longitude), in which direction (azimuth and elevation) the camera is pointing, together with the field of view. Then you project this onto the geodata of the environment and from there you can do all kinds of things, like finding the 3D position of an object based on its location in the photograph.

Comment: finding the 3D position of an object based on its location in the photograph.

Comment: If you have the parameters I mentioned you'll be able to project your photograph onto a 3D model of the landscape from where you'll be able to find the 3D location of the object from the projection.